# how to download server file in node js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Could you please tell me how to download server file in node js

here is my code
**Node js code (request code)**

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;


// use of body parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());



app.get('/download', function(req, res){
    console.log(__dirname);
    var file = path.join(__dirname , '/uploads/file-1534458777206.xlsx');
    console.log(file)
    res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.
});




app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is listening to ${PORT}`);
})
```

I am requesting like that **on client**

```
$('.download').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/download',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('data')
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // Handle errors here
                    console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
                    // STOP LOADING SPINNER
                }
            });
```

**getting error** on console

```
ERRORS: parsererror
3index.html?_ijt=9lu9erpan2oq6qf28851ngj0ra:32 ERRORS: parsererror
2index.html?_ijt=9lu9erpan2oq6qf28851ngj0ra:32 ERRORS: parsererror
```

**server logs**

```
C:\Users\B0207296\WebstormProjects\uploadFile\server
C:\Users\B0207296\WebstormProjects\uploadFile\server\uploads\file-1534458777206.xlsx
```

why files is not download on client as I mention file is present in above url

Comment: What happens when on click you do `$window.open(http://localhost:3000/download)`

Comment: it donload the file in new tab

Comment: using this it dowload the file window.open(http://localhost:3000/download) .in new tab

Comment: Ok so your server is working fine. I think the users browser is protecting them. I don't know of any way to download a file from an ajax request directly. Try the "virtual click link" method here i guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164277/download-file-on-ajax-success-node-js

Comment: ok thanks for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery returning "parsererror" for ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061310/jquery-returning-parsererror-for-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the file content via ajax:
Just remove the dataType, your file is being parsed to json causing the error.

```
$('.download').on('click', function () {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://localhost:3000/download',
          type: 'GET',
          success: function (data) {
              console.log(data); // File data
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              // Handle errors here
              console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
              // STOP LOADING SPINNER
          }
      });
```

To download the file is better user a virtual link

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<b class="download">Download Here</b>
<script>
$('.download').on('click', function () {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = 'http://localhost:3000/download';
    var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    e.initEvent('click', true, true);
    link.dispatchEvent(e);
  })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes `success is` coming now but file is not downloaded why ?

Comment: file is donload correctly or successfully using this `window.location ='http://localhost:3000/download';`

Comment: but it is not downloded using ajax

Comment: In this case you got the file content in the ajax request. If you want to download it's better use the Virtual Link Click strategy.