# Angular cannot get file download from express using res.download

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my application I create a file on the backend, and I wish then to deliver that to the user via a browser download.  I have tried numerous

Here is the express backend:

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
  res.download('filename.txt', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
})
```

The console call isn't returning, so presumably no error. Here is what I am doing in the front-end, following advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176982/res-download-not-working-in-my-case) and here:

```
window.open('localhost:3000/download');
```

The result is that I get a blank window popping up, but no download. I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164277/download-file-on-ajax-success-node-js):

```
const filePath = 'localhost:3000/download/';
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = filePath;
link.download = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
link.click();
```

But in this case, nothing happens.

What am i doing wrong? I at a loss even how to debug any further.

### Update 1

Thanks @jal_a, I've made progress.  I realise now that if I manually create a window and enter the url (as suggested) the download works.  However, when the window is launched from the application using `window.open(url)` where url is the same, the window opens but the download doesn't initiate.  If I then go to the created window, click in the url and press return ... voila! It works!  How can I make the download initiate from the application launched window?

### Update 2

Thanks @IceMetalPunk, I tried that and I'm getting the following error in the console - the file I'm trying to download is gps data in gpx format - which I can see in the response, but it seems to be expecting JSON??  Do I need to do any pre-processing to send a file?:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", 
url: "http://localhost:3000/download/", ok: false, …}
error:
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse 

...

text: "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
↵<gpx version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0">
↵   <rte>
↵      <name>undefined</name>
↵      <rtept lat="50.70373" lon="-3.07241" />
↵      <rtept lat="50.70348" lon="-3.07237" />
↵   </rte>
↵</gpx>"
__proto__: Object
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: 
ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/download/"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:3000/download/"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Comment: Just go to `localhost:3000/download` in your browser and see if you get the download. If not then the issue is on your backend. Check the network request in developer tools of the browser to get more insight on what you get as response.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of this, but I believe that if you use the Content-Disposition header (which is what Express sends when you use `res.download`), you don't need to open a pop-up window. You can just navigate directly to the download page, and the browser won't leave the current page, instead it'll just ask the user to save the download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my download link did not include the `http://` element of the url, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54053901/cannot-get-browser-to-initiate-download-from-express) describes.