# Cannot get browser to initiate download from express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981780/angular-cannot-get-file-download-from-express-using-res-download?noredirect=1#comment94894474_53981780) question, I cannot get the browser to initiate a download from express.  Backend code:

```
app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
  res.download('./textfile.txt', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('error: ' + err);
    }   else {
      console.log('success');
    }
  });
})
```

I have changed from a .gpx file to text file to ensure its nothing to do with that, and I have tried playing with the headers as below, to no avail:

```
res.header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
res.header('Content-Security-Policy', 'upgrade-insecure-requests');
```

On the front-end I have tried:

```
window.location.href = 'localhost:3000/download';
```

and:

```
const filePath = 'localhost:3000/download';
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = filePath;
link.download = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
link.click();
```

and:

```
const newWindow = window.open('localhost:3000/download', 'download');
```

and navigating to the backend url via GET request (per response to my original question), but none of them initiate the download in the browser.

I think it is a front-end problem, as when I double-click on the download in the console, it opens.  The front end is getting the data, but the browser (chrome) is not downloading it. I also tried Firefox, same result.

There are many queries similar to this, but none have solved the issue for me.

Comment: Open the url `localhost:3000/download` in your browser and see if it downloads. If not then your express server is the issue or check the network panel in dev tools.

Comment: yes, that works without issue.  File auto-downloads.  The issue is I think with the front-end - I cannot get the browser to initiate the download in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you are not passing the correct url to `window.open`. You need to include `http://`

```
window.open('http://localhost:3000/download');
```

Comment: aw, flippin' 'eck. I knew i would be obvious when I found it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For security purpose it is said that you have to open new tab if you want to download something.
So use

```
window.open('http://localhost:3000/download','_blank')
```